# Codeigniter query with alias and number as column

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to replace column name with numbers in codeigniter

It does work well with letters but not with numbers

```
$this->db->select ('Observation.id_observation as 1');
            $this->db->from ( 'Observation' );
            $this->db->join ( 'Enregistrement', 'Enregistrement.id_observation = 
             Observation.id_observation' , 'left' );
            $this->db->where('Observation.id_parcelle', $id_parcelle);
            $this->db->where('Observation.id_observateur', $user_id);
            $this->db->where('Observation.date_observation >=', $date_start);
            $this->db->where('Observation.date_observation <=', $date_end);
            return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: $this->db->select ('Observation.id_observation as ` 1 ` ');

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

$this->db->select ("Observation.id_observation as '1'");

Hope It will work.

Comment: It does work in mysql but not within codeigniter, i'll try as a custom query in codeigniter

Comment: Here are the working example :
See the attach screenshot:

https://prnt.sc/q3rd73
https://prnt.sc/q3rdlr

Answer (score 0):

**You can set alias name as string so you need to give within single quotes otherwise you will get syntax error**

```
                $this->db->select ('Observation.id_observation as `1`',FALSE);
                $this->db->from ( 'Observation' );
                $this->db->join ( 'Enregistrement', 'Enregistrement.id_observation = 
                 Observation.id_observation' , 'left' );
                $this->db->where('Observation.id_parcelle', $id_parcelle);
                $this->db->where('Observation.id_observateur', $user_id);
                $this->db->where('Observation.date_observation >=', $date_start);
                $this->db->where('Observation.date_observation <=', $date_end);
                return $this->db->get()->result();
```

**OR**

```
$var = '1';
$this->db->select ('Observation.id_observation as `'.$var.'`',FALSE);
```

**OR**

```
 $query=$this->db->query('SELECT Observation.id_observation as "1" FROM Observation LEFT JOIN Enregistrement ON Enregistrement.id_observation = 
   Observation.id_observation WHERE Observation.id_parcelle = '.$id_parcelle.' AND Observation.id_observateur = '.$user_id.' AND Observation.date_observation >= "'.$date_start.'" AND Observation.date_observation <= "'.$date_end.'" ');
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: use apostrophe symbol

Comment: can u try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$this->db->select ('Observation.id_observation as `1`');
```

This will generate query as

```
Select `observation` as `1`....
```

From the Docs

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Comment: Can you check the query generated using `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: It returns this : SELECT `Observation`.`id_observation` as `1`
FROM `Observation`
LEFT JOIN `Enregistrement` ON `Enregistrement`.`id_observation` = `Observation`.`id_observation`
WHERE `Observation`.`id_parcelle` = '47'
AND `Observation`.`id_observateur` = '84'
AND `Observation`.`date_observation` >= '2019-03-05'
AND `Observation`.`date_observation` <= '2019-04-05'

Comment: It does work on local with xampp but not on my hosting server !

Answer (score -1):

This is what i had to do in the controller ! I very don't like this solultion but it does work:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                $sql = "SELECT 
                Observation.id_observation as '0', 
                Observation.checkseries as '1'
                FROM Observation 
                LEFT JOIN Enregistrement ON Enregistrement.id_observation = Observation.id_observation
                WHERE 
                Observation.id_parcelle = '$parcellecultures->id_parcelle'
                AND Observation.id_observateur = '$user'
                AND Observation.date_observation >= '$date_start'
                AND Observation.date_observation <= '$date_end'
                ";
                //echo $sql;
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                //print_r($result);exit;
                $conn->close();
```

I still look for another solution ....